# Moving the cursor to the bottom left of the console

Tags: c++, linux, ansi-escape

How can I move the cursor position in the linux console to the bottom left? I know I can write

```
std::cout << "\033[1;1H";
```

to move the cursor to the upper left.
However [there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_codes) is apparently no code to move it to the bottom left with one command.

I don't want to use an extern library like ncurses.

Comment: Standard libraries know how to do this for a variety of different terminal types.   What terminal type are you targetting?   If you want it to work on many different terminals, you'll be in for a lot of work, I suspect...

Comment: It's for a private project at home, so it's okay. EDIT: I'm targeting the standard Ubuntu terminal.

Comment: Libraries like ncurses handle determining the height and width of the terminal for you, based on what happens to be in `$TERM` and the contents of your terminfo database. If you want to position the cursor yourself, you'll need to detect this information yourself - which is not very simple.

Answer (score 3):

xterm can do this explicitly (see [*XTerm Control Sequences*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Controls-beginning-with-ESC:ESC-F.C74)):

```
std::cout << "\033F";
```

or in the shell

```
printf '\033F'
```

but not all "xterm" lookalikes implement everything that xterm does.  For those, you can make a "good enough" solution by telling it to move ***far*** down on the left margin.  This would work for any terminal you are likely to use:

```
std::cout << "\033[9999;1H";
```

in shell:

```
tput cup 9999 0
```

(assuming your terminal had fewer than 10,000 rows).

Answer (score 0):

Your "standard Ubuntu terminal" probably supports xterm escape codes: http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html

See specifically:

> CSI P s ; P s ; P s t
>   P s = 1 9 → Report the size of the screen in characters. Result is CSI 9 ; height ; width t

...and...

> ESC Y P s P s    Move the cursor to given row and column.

"CSI" is explained at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: I understand CSI and Ps and so on. But where is the result saved? Can you show me a C++ example?

Comment: The result is sent back to standard input... you can read it from `std::cin`.  I could show an example, but hopefully knowing where to read the result from means you can give it a try and ask a specific question if you have trouble....

Comment: So, I tried this:

    std::cout << "\033[t";  
    std::string str;  
    std::cin >> str;  
    std::cout << str << std::endl;  

But that does not print anything.